# Page looking funny before css loads fully

Tags: css, image, loading

I have this site where it loads not quite fully before the css loads and the whole page looks funny for about a second.  It's made with wordpress so there could be some serving time but nothing that I would think that would do this.

http://hanrattyassoc.u4eastaging.com/section/product-highlight/

[image: what it looks like for a second]

Comment: nothing ;) It's the way of the web. You could serve a empty page only loading the css and then add the rest using javascript, but I think that would be overdoing it. Users are accustomed to loading time.

Comment: Have you tried moving your CSS links from the foot of the page into the head?

Comment: Loading JavaScript files at the end of the `<body></body>` is good practice.  Loading CSS files anyplace outside of the `<head></head>` is not good practice.

Answer (score -2):

You do can do a work-around.
Add style **display : none** OR **opacity : 0**  to body & Create a jquery function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(body).animate({
      opacity : 1 }, 
      100
    );
```

This will show your body after browser done with all css & script load.